# Can you add options to a Quickbook Invoice?

Tags: quickbooks

Our lab is making a spin-off non-profit, and we were considering using Quickbooks online to help with the expected light load of book keeping.  One of the things we would really like to be able to do is send an invoice with options that could be selected and then incorporated into the total.

So, for example, we might quote out a price to mount samples onto slides and return them, with an optional add-in/up-sell that we scan the slides before sending them back.  Ideally, we would be creating the invoices from our local billing software and then using the Quickbooks API to create a new invoice to send to the collaborator.

Looking at their developer and API, I couldn't find anything remotely close to this.  Is it possible to have the receiver of the invoice pay different amounts biassed selected options?  It would be fine if we did the coding on our side, I just couldn't see where to begin (we could start making our own WebForms, but that would defeat one of the main advantages to Quickbooks in the first place).